# How to add a item from a list to another page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a beginner in Xamarin.form. I would like to add the products to my shopping cart when I click the button. I tried and have no idea how to get this item and send to shopping cart page.
Here is my xmal:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="productsListView" ItemSelected="OnProductSelected" HasUnevenRows="true"  SeparatorVisibility="None" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="Handle_Refreshing">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell >
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="2">

                         <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>

                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >

                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" />

                            <Label Text="{Binding Price}" TextColor="Gray"/>

                         </StackLayout>

                           <Button Text="+" Clicked="Add_To_ShoppingCart" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

                    </StackLayout>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>

                             <MenuItem Text="AddToNotify"/>

                             <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" Clicked="OnDeleteProduct" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
              </ViewCell>   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I don't know how to get the productName and send it shopping cart page, so the shopping cart page could search it from the database and displays it.

Button code:

```cs
   async void Add_To_ShoppingCart(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //var product = (sender as Button).CommandParameter as Product;

        //var shoppingcartPage = new ShoppingCartPage(product);

        //shoppingcartPage.BindingContext = product.ProductID;

        //await Navigation.PushAsync(shoppingcartPage);

        var product = new Product()
        {
            ProductName= Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        var shoppingcarpage = new ShoppingCartPage(product);
        shoppingcarpage.BindingContext = product;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(shoppingcarpage);

        //var product = HomepageListView.

        //await conn.InsertAsync(product);

        //_products.Add(product);
    }
```

I tried PushAsync like click the product and it goes to product detail page. I don't want to create a new page like that. Just add an item to shopping cart. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to review how the shopping cart works in the reference app, eShopOnContainers, github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers `Open eShopOnContainers-MobileApps.sln for a solution containing just the client mobile app projects (Xamarin mobile apps only). It works independently based on mocks, too.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you'll finish making an image button...

```xml
<Image
    Source="btnadd.png"
    HeightRequest="24">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="BtnAdd_OnTapped" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

As you can see you're passing the whole product to you tap/click handler. After that it's easy to add it to your cart list..

```cs
 public class CustomParam
 {
     public Product Parameter { get; set; }
 }
 private void BtnAdd_OnTapped(object sender, CustomParam e)
 {
     var product = e.Parameter;
     //pls add me to cart now.. plsplspls :)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I did it by storing the data into database and read it from another page. hhhhhh, now I got a new model name shoppingcart~